# Copy and Paste Macro Containing For Loop

Tags: vba, excel

The macro below loops through column E in Sheet2 and finds matches in column Z of Sheet1. If a match is found it copies the value on the same row contained in column AA.

It works ok but hangs when it runs. There are usually a few thousand values in column E but less than 30 in column Z.

I've run it on a few PCs with decent specs but always have the same issue.

Are there any ways to optimise it?

Example Data:

Sheet1, column Z:

| Z |
| --- |
| 42039505 |
| 40642035 |
| 40191591 |
| 23239795 |
| 38593074 |

Sheet1, column AA:

| AA |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| R |
| E |
| 8 |

Sheet2, column E

| E |
| --- |
| 42039505 |
| 40642035 |
| 40191591 |
| 23239795 |
| 38593074 |
| 42039505 |
| 40642035 |
| 40191591 |
| 23239795 |
| 38593074 |
| 42039505 |
| 40642035 |
| 40191591 |
| 23239795 |
| 38593074 |

```
Sub CopyResult()

Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim c As Range
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng1 = WS1.Range(WS1.Range("E2"), WS1.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set Rng2 = WS2.Range(WS2.Range("Z5"), WS2.Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each c In Rng1
On Error Resume Next

Rng2.Find(What:=c).Offset(, 1).Copy Destination:=c.Offset(, 19) 
Err.Clear
Next c

Set WS1 = Nothing
Set WS2 = Nothing
Set Rng1 = Nothing
Set Rng2 = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  It's best to describe **what value this code provides to its user**.

Comment: Could you give a small before and after snippet? So for every ID in `Sheet1.colE`, you check if that ID is in `Sheet2.colZ`, if so you take the corresponding value from `Sheet2.colAA` and copy it to `Sheet1.colP`? Also why are you using VBA rather than some kind of Lookup formula in excel? Is your data formatted as an Excel table/can it be? You can paste tables from excel to markdown and add them directly to your post https://thisdavej.com/copy-table-in-excel-and-paste-as-a-markdown-table/

Comment: Hi @Greedo, your understanding is correct except that it is colZ in Sheet1 and colE in Sheet2. I have added some snippets to the post. For various reasons I can't use formulas or tables. Thanks

Comment: You wrote : _There are usually a few thousand values in column E but **less than 30 in column Z**_ ---> I wonder if there is a reason that instead of using the value in sheet1 column Z if it's found in sheet2 column E, you use the value in sheet2 column E if it's found in sheet1 column Z ? I ask because in your code there is no something like this :  _if this looped cell value is found in column Z then do blablabla, if this looped cell value is not found in column Z then do blublublu to this looped cell value_.

Comment: So, maybe something like this ? `for each c in Rng2: c.offset(0,1).copy destination:= Rng1.cells.find(c.value).offset(0,19)` ---> this will loop to the "less than 30" data in sheet1 column Z, copy the looped cell.offset(0,1) value then paste to the found looped cell.offset(0,19) in sheet2 column E. Not tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A Classic VBA Lookup

[image]

**Pros**

- First of all, congratulations, the code compiles which could indicate that you understand the importance of `Option Explicit`.
- Mostly you understand the importance of qualifying objects which includes qualifying the worksheets which you do with `ThisWorkbook`, the workbook containing this code.
- You are correctly looping through column `E` of the destination worksheet `Sheet2` that has a ton of duplicates, to lookup values in column `Z` of the source worksheet `Sheet1` that should have unique (distinct) values.
- You are not lazy to use `Next` without the control variable `c`.

**Cons**

- Using variables like `WS1` and `WS2` is bad practice i.e. already in a day or two, it won't be so easy to determine which one is the source and which one the destination worksheet not to mention the additional confusion you introduced by using `WS1` for `Sheet2` and `WS2` for `Sheet1`.
- There is no room for `On Error Resume Next` when using the `Find` method. Also, the prescribed way to use it is:

  ```
  On Error Resume Next
  Whatever
  On Error Goto 0
  ```
- Adding another variable and testing it against `Nothing` is the way to go. Also, copying by assignment is faster then using the `Copy` method.

  ```
  Dim sCell As Range

  For Each c In Rng1.Cells
      Set sCell = Rng2.Find(...)
      If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
          c.Offset(...).Value = sCell.Offset(...).Value 
      End If
  Next
  ```
- What are you looping through? Through cells. So use `... In Rng1.Cells`.
- Using offset in this way is bad practice. Sure, everyone immediately knows the column adjacent to the right of column `Z` but I don't think that anyone will instantly know that `19` columns to the right of column `E` is column `X`.
- The `Find` method has many more arguments so you should utilize them, in this case especially the 4th argument, the `LookAt` argument with the parameter `xlWhole` or `xlPart` which is saved each time the `Find` method is used.
- The series of lines `Set Whatever = Nothing` are totally redundant and they gotta go.

**Nit Picking**

- You are not using constants.
- You have put the variable declarations at the beginning, far from the action. I prefer to have them closer, and since there will be more than a dozen of them in my code, I wouldn't want that wall of variables at the beginning of my code.
- I prefer to use a variable for the workbook even if it is `ThisWorkbook` so in the case I would want to use a different workbook, I would have to change it only in one place.
- I would put `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` right before the loop indicating that this is where the action begins.
- You haven't qualified the `Rows` in `Rows.Count` e.g.: `WS1.Rows.Count`.

**Status**

- The bottleneck is that you're looping through tens of thousands of cells in the destination lookup column. You can't turn off enough settings for it to not take forever to finish.
- The use of `Application.Match` instead of the `Find` method would increase efficiency a bit but I won't go down that road since it won't make enough of a difference.

**The Plan**

- In the source worksheet (`Sheet1`), write the values from the lookup column (`Z`) and the corresponding values, the values in the same row, from the return column (`AA`) to arrays, loop through the arrays and write the lookup values to the `keys`, and the return values to the `items` of a dictionary. Erase the arrays.
- In the destination worksheet (`Sheet2`), write the values from the lookup column (`E`) to another array and use yet another array of the same size to write the matches to it. Then write the matches to the return column (`X`).
- Use a message box to not wonder if the code has run or not since it is 'lightning' fast.

### The Main Procedure

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LookupData()

    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL As String = "Z5"
    Const SRC_RETURN_COL As String = "AA"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL As String = "E2"
    Const DST_RETURN_COL As String = "X"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    ' The `Find` or the `End` method would fail if the worksheet were filtered.
    If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL)
    
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = RefColumn(sfCell)
    If slrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in column range
    Dim slData(): slData = GetSingleColumnRange(slrg)
    
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_RETURN_COL)
    Dim srData(): srData = GetSingleColumnRange(srrg)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = DictTwoSingleColumns(slData, srData)
    If dict Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' only error values and blanks
    
    Erase slData
    Erase srData
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    ' The `Find` or the `End` method would fail if the worksheet were filtered.
    If dws.FilterMode Then dws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL)
    
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = RefColumn(dfCell)
    If dlrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in column range
    Dim dlData(): dlData = GetSingleColumnRange(dlrg)
    
    Dim drData(): drData = GetLookedUpColumnInDict(dlData, dict)
    Dim drrg As Range: Set drrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_RETURN_COL)
    drrg.Value = drData
    
    MsgBox "Data looked up.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

### The Help

- Note that the last two procedures aren't as flexible as the first two i.e. their parameters are restricted to 2D single-column column arrays while the last is additionally restricted to a one-based array. The keys of the dictionary are values converted to strings and in the last procedure, the lookup values are converted to strings.

**Reference a Single Column Range**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      References the range from a given cell to the bottom-most
'               non-empty cell in same column.
' Remarks:      It will fail if the worksheet is filtered.
'               It will not fail if the worksheet has hidden rows or columns.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Dim rg As Range
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Set rg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not rg Is Nothing Then Set rg = .Resize(rg.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then Set RefColumn = rg
End Function
```

**Single Column Range To Array**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a given column of a range
'               in a 2D one-based single-column array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetSingleColumnRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnNumber As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    If ColumnNumber < 1 Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber > rg.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
    Dim Data()
    With rg.Areas(1).Columns(ColumnNumber)
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Rows.Count
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Data = .Value
        End If
    End With
    GetSingleColumnRange = Data
End Function
```

**Source Lookup and Return Values To Dictionary**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the unique values from a given 2D one-based
'               single-column array, converted to strings, in the 'keys',
'               and the corresponding values, the values in the same rows
'               of another given same sized array, not converted to strings,
'               in the 'items' of a dictionary.
' Remarks:      Error values and blanks are excluded.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function DictTwoSingleColumns( _
    DataKeys() As Variant, _
    DataItems() As Variant) _
As Object

    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = LBound(DataKeys, 1) To UBound(DataKeys, 1)
        Key = DataKeys(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(CStr(Key)) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(CStr(Key)) = DataItems(r, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
   
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function ' only error values and blanks
    
    Set DictTwoSingleColumns = dict

End Function
```

**Return Values From Dictionary To Array**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      From a given dictionary, returns the corresponding looked up
'               values, converted to strings, of a given 2D one-based
'               single-column array, in another same-sized array.
' Remarks:      The 'keys' of the dictionary need also to be strings while
'               the 'items' can be simple variants (not objects or arrays).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetLookedUpColumnInDict( _
    Data() As Variant, _
    ByVal dict As Object) _
As Variant()
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To 1)
    Dim r As Long, rString As String
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        rString = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        If Len(rString) > 0 Then
            If dict.Exists(rString) Then dData(r, 1) = dict(rString)
        End If
    Next r
    GetLookedUpColumnInDict = dData
End Function
```

Comment: this is amazing, thank you. It will take some time for me to digest! Much appreciated.

Comment: This works perfectly. I have also learned a lot. Thanks once again.